# Python function to send things between 2 users?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, function

I am trying to learn python ( and programming in general). For now I am trying to make a simple bank where users can send/deposit/withdraw money.
I have already created the deposit and withdraw functions and are working. Now I am totally confused on how to write the send function as the user will be sending money and the other will be receiving the money.
Should I write 2 seperate functions fo send and receive, but then how to trigger both in the same time? ( another function containing both) ?

I hope you can help me with this,
so far this is my code:
Classes:

```
class Account(object):
def __init__(self, name, account_number, initial_amount):
    self.name = name
    self.no = account_number
    self.balance = initial_amount

def deposit(self, amount):
    self.balance += amount

def withdraw(self, amount):
    self.balance -= amount

def dump(self):
    s = '%s, %s, balance: %s' % \
        (self.name, self.no, self.balance)
    print s

def get_balance(self):
    print(self.balance)

def send(self, sender, receiver, amount):
    self.sender = sender
    self.receiver = receiver
    self.balance -= amount
```

main.py:

```
from classes.Account import Account

a1 = Account('John Doe', '19371554951', 20000)
a2 = Account('Jenny Doe',  '19371564761', 20000)
a1.deposit(1000)
a1.withdraw(4000)
a2.withdraw(10500)
a2.withdraw(3500)

a1.get_balance()
```

I know this may be basic, but I hope I can get help here.

Thank you

Comment: I think you want a Bank class, with a method to transfer(amount, from_account, to_account)

Comment: Why do you think there needs to be a Bank class to supervise the transfer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have `deposit` and `withdraw` methods so you might as well use them.

Transferring money is essentially withdrawing from one account and depositing it in another.

This can be implemented with a static method that accepts 2 accounts and the amount which will encapsulate the idea of "transfer":

```
class Account:
    .
    .
    .

    @staticmethod
    def transfer(from_account, to_account, amount):
        from_account.withdraw(amount)
        to_account.deposit(amount)
        # TODO perhaps you will want to use a try-except block 
        # to implement a transaction: if either withdrawing or depositing 
        # fails you will want to rollback the changes.
```

usage:

```
from classes.Account import Account

a1 = Account('John Doe', '19371554951', 20000)
a2 = Account('Jenny Doe',  '19371564761', 20000)
print(a1.balance)
print(a2.balance)
Account.transfer(a1, a2, 10)
print(a1.balance)
print(a2.balance)
#  20000
#  20000
#  19990
#  20010
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn`t know about static methods.

Comment: Is there a need to have some kind of lock on the user account to ensure balance is right if there are multiple withdrawals?

Comment: @naivepredictor Maybe and maybe not. That was not the premise of the question

Comment: no worrie, thanks anywa. btw. what protocol shall be used for efficient user to user payment?

Comment: imagine, user1 talks to gateway that talks to payment handling system that talks back to user2. so, if user1 wants to send money to user2 does he talk via https to rest api? or shall he use xmpp like kind of messaging protocol?